# How to Set Metadata Navigation Setting to Document Library using Visual studio

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, managed-navigation

How to Set Metadata Navigation Setting to Document Library using Visual studio.

[image]

Comment: can you elaborate your question more?

Comment: I create this ManageNavigationSetting using Browser.I create this Document Library using Visual studio.So I want to add This setting in VS.How can I do this using VS?